# join used cars store queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a dataset of a used cars store, and in the first query I have the total cars and respective car year. In the second query I have the cars that have been sold and respective car year. Third query is only the cars that have not been sold yet.

My goal is to join these 3 columns. I tried but the values don't work; in the last query you can see what I tried to achieve, but it returns me no registers.

[First Query - Total Cars Qty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiOku.png)

[Second Query - Sold Cars Qty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2ziQ.png)

[Third Query - Not Sold Cars Qty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x6cY.png)

[Fourth Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdWV6.png)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
[mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: Thanks! I'll follow these steps next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last query doesn't work, because you are using

```
where t3.sold = 'Y'
and t4.sold = 'N'
```

and a single Sales_ID can not be both sold an not sold. So you could remove these clauses from **WHERE** block and add them to **JOIN ON** conditions, like:

```
LEFT JOIN [Portfolio Project].dbo.Car_Detail t3
on t3.Sales_ID = t1.Sales_ID
and t3.sold = 'Y'
```

But actually, you don't need to use all three joins in this exact case. Try using cases inside of count() instead:

```
select  t2.[year], 
        count(t1.sold) as TOTAL_CAR_NUMBER,
        count(case when t1.sold = 'Y' then t1.sold else null end) as SOLD_CAR_NUMBER,
        count(case when t1.sold = 'N' then t1.sold else null end) as NOTSOLD_CAR_NUMBER,
FROM [Portfolio Project].dbo.Selling_Prrice t1
    INNER JOIN [Portfolio Project].dbo.Car_Detail t2
        on t1.Sales_ID = t2.Sales_ID
group by t2.[year]
order by t2.[year]
```

Comment: 'You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote' tried to upvote, but already marked as an answer ;)